# Impossible to start httpd on centos 5.5

Tags: centos, httpd

I'm having trouble to start my httpd server.

When I try to start it, I get this output :

```
Starting httpd: httpd:apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for coyote.localdomain
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

I've read on the net that the first message would be caused by misconfiguration of the /etc/hosts file.
Although my file seems to be OK :

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
my.vm.i.p    coyote
```

I also run apachectl -S which gave me the following output :

```
httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for coyote.localdomain
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
     default server 127.0.0.1 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:81)
     port 443 namevhost 127.0.0.1 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:81)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server a1.template.company.net (/etc/httpd/conf.d/a1.template.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost a1.template.company.net (/etc/httpd/conf.d/a1.template.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost a2.template.company.net (/etc/httpd/conf.d/a2.template.conf:1)
Syntax OK
```

When I try to start the server in debug mode, there is no more useful information than in normal start mode, except the full list of modules (correctly loaded)

Do you have any idea of what could be wrong ?

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: what does `hostname` from the command line give you? BTW, why not just set `ServerName` in your httpd.conf?

Comment: `hostname` gives me `coyote.localdomain`. Sorry to be newbish, but what should I set with `ServerName` in httpd.conf ?

Comment: Does that seem like a FQDN to you? I still think you'd just be better off setting the `ServerName` and `Listen` values in your httpd configuration, it's better that way.

Comment: Even if I set for instance `coyote.company.net` in /etc/hosts I still get the `apr_sockaddr_info_get()` error.

Comment: First, type `hostname coyote.company.net` Then go set `Listen` and `ServerName` in your httpd configuration.

Comment: Ok cheers, that removed the error but I still get failed status to start the server, without any error message. Although I've this in the error_log `[Fri Apr 04 13:19:44 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context root:system_r:hotplug_t:SystemLow-SystemHigh
[Fri Apr 04 13:19:44 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Apr 04 13:19:44 2014] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled`

Comment: The error will be showing up somewhere, either in the system log, or specifically in the httpd logs (wherver they are located).

Comment: Ahhh, for the moment you can set Selinux to permissive by running `setenforce 0` and then try restarting apache.

Comment: I ran `setenforce 0` but still nothing changed (in the error_log I get now `SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context root:system_r:httpd_t`). Would suexec cause troubles as well ?

Comment: That's normal as far as I know, there's nothing else after that in the logs?

Comment: nope, only suexec and ssl fips notice logs... And there is nothing related to httpd in /var/log/messages

Comment: Why is your server so far out of date? Update the system and try again.